# PhotoSwipe - How to align image vertical top on zoom-in?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'm using [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/) to show vertical images, really tall vertical images. 
When I click on the image, by default, the zoom is applied on the center of the image, but I need to be aligned to the top. That is: considering that the vertical images are very tall, I want that zooming-in starts on top of the image, so I can scroll down and see the rest of the image.

I've been playing with some options of the [documentation](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html), but I can't figure it out. Does anyone have to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Not sure if it's the way to do it, but it works.

Before initializing the PhotoSwipe gallery, declare a custom function that uses the PhotoSwipe API to zoom and align the image:

```
function zoomtop() {
    gallery.zoomTo(1, {x:0, y:0});
}
var gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
gallery.init();
zoomtop();
gallery.listen('afterChange', function() {zoomtop()});
```

That would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 I am doing it like this:

```
const pswp = new PhotoSwipe({
  ...restOptions,
  initialZoomLevel: 'fill',
})
pswp.init()
const toTop = () => {
  pswp.currSlide.panTo(0, 0)
  const els = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.pswp__zoom-wrap')
  els.forEach((el) => {
    const transformParts = el.style.transform.split(',')
    transformParts[1] = ' 0px'
    el.style.transform = transformParts.join(',')
  })
}
pswp.on('change', function () {
  toTop()
})
pswp.on('openingAnimationEnd', function () {
  toTop()
})
```